# OAuth 2.0 Single-use Access Token for unauthenticated user via IdentityServer4

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, identityserver4

*I apologies in advance for incorrect use of oauth terms*.

I have 4 "parties" as follows (intentionally not using oauth terms where possible):

- End-user in a browser *(javascript)*
- Our website *(aspnet)*
- Our web api *(aspnet)*
- Our auth server *(aspnet utilising identityserver 4)*

My usage scenario is that we only want the API to be called by a browser that has requested a page from the website first. Whilst the API doesn't release sensitive information, we would like to introduce a layer of complexity with regards to the API being spammed.

Our end user's will **not be logged in**.

I imagine such a flow being akin:

1. Browser requests a certain page from the website *(one that will likely lead to js making an api call)*
2. Website requests token from auth server
3. Auth server verifies token request came from website (the server itself)
4. Auth server returns a token to the website
5. Website returns page including the access token
6. Browser is able to make a request to api using token

Although convoluted, I believe this is at least similar to the Client Access Grant flow?

These tokens could then be *throttled* either by website or auth server.

*Yes, I'm aware that this doesn't protect the api from numerous other vectors, but it does eliminate the simplest of cases which is all we're looking to achieve for now. I'll add, I didn't define this requirement, I'm simply trying to find a way to achieve it utilising techs out there instead of making the mistake of rolling anything of my own.*

Could someone confirm/deny that there is an oauth flow I could use here? Any sample projects using the given flow and IdentityServer?

*IdentityServer3 / non-aspnet[core/5] examples are fine, I can translate*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is the [Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) where your website (client) gets an access token from identityserver (auth server). That access token can then be used to call endpoints on your web API (resource server).

The token is a bearer token and can be used by anyone who has it, so if you are comfortable with your website passing it back to a browser on an HTTP response, then it will work just fine.

I'm not sure what you mean by throttling the tokens - once minted they are valid for their lifetime. I guess you can keep the time-to-live very short to achieve the single usage you want though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @iandayman. Do you know of any examples of the Client Credentials Grant using IdentityServer?

Comment: @Smudge202 Have a look at https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/simplestOAuth.html